# Using C# Script in SharePoint Page

Tags: c#, html, sharepoint

I've done quite a bit of searching (several hours actually) but I haven't been able to get this working. Basically, I have this button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Go!" id="go" onClick="getDoc()" />
```

and this block of script:

```
<script type="c#" runat="server">

public void getDoc(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Test to see if function was running (it's not...)
    DocFrame.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.google.com";

    // Get the current state of the dropdowns   
    String dropYear = (String)Year.SelectedValue;
    String dropDiv = (String)Division.SelectedValue;
    String dropControl = (String)Control.SelectedValue;
    String dropQuart= (String)Quarter.SelectedValue;

    // Get the Site where the list is
    using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite("http://portal/Corporate/IT/")) {
        using (SPWeb web = siteCol.RootWeb){
            // Get the list items we need
            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems("Year", "Division", "Control", "Quarter");
            SPListItem item = null;
            // Loop through them until we find a matching everything
            foreach (SPListItem it in items){

                if(it.Year == dropYear && it.Division == dropDiv && it.Control == dropControl && it.Quarter == dropQuart){
                    item = it;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Assign the item as a string  
            String URL = (String)item["Title"];
            // Set the iframe to the new URL
            DocFrame.Attributes["src"] = URL;
        }   
    }
}
```

It's all in the page where this is happening, please keep in mind that I've been using sharepoint for less than a week and have only ever coded in C++, so I could be doing everything horribly wrong. Anyway, it seems that getDoc() is never even getting called, so can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
onClick="getDoc()"
```

you should do

```
OnClick="getDoc"
```

That's the proper way to wire an up an event.

By the way, you should consider following [C# Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). If you were using better naming, it might look like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Go!" id="GoBtn" onClick="GoBtn_Click" />
```

Common practice convention is to append the event name after the ID of the control. It's not required, but it looks cleaner and other developers like to see that when they look at your code.

Also, `DocFrame.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.google.com";` is not a good way to see if the function is running. It doesn't update the page in realtime, as the entire server side function executes, then the results are sent to the client. Instead, [use your IDE's debugging tools](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio) to hook up to the server and set code breaks etc. Or what I do is have the code send me an email, I created a little utility library for that.

Comment: I changed that and it's still not working. When I click the button, the iframe seems to reload, but nothing happens. Am I changing the src correctly? Thanks for you help. (And thanks for the naming help too!)

Comment: @user3669439 See the update to my answer, the last paragraph.

Comment: Well, the reason I used that is because that's what I'm trying to do in the rest of the code - change the iframe to a different URL. If that doesn't work there, than what I'm trying to do won't work either. Is there a better way to change the src when the user clicks go? I did it Javascript and it worked, but I needed to use C# to access my list.

Comment: @kylebshr I'm not saying that you can't change the src. But I am saying that's not a good way to tell if the server side function is being called. You need to step through the code with your IDE's debugger and make sure the execution is happening the way you expect it to, so that the src will get update properly.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for you help! I'll see if I can get it working. Any tips on debugging in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Yes. Switch from SharepointDesigner to something else, preferably Visual Studio Pro. I know, it costs money. But many .NET developers are in love with VS.